# 500 Internal Server Error When I try to execute web method from different Server IIS

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I am trying to call a Webmethod by ajax call.The webmethod has been implemented in to a .asmx file.When I publish the project and deploy in my local server IIS. Then the webmethod successfully executed from my local IIS .But when I deploy the same published version into different server IIS and try to access the Webmethod then I am getting "500 Internal Server Error".

I Cannot not understand why the same code behaving different.What mistake I am doing please suggest.

The code has been written as follows -

Code in .cshtml file

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/Root/Shared/CommonServices.asmx/SubmitRequestInterface2",
  data: 
    { 'fromDate': $("#txtBeginData").val(), 
      'toDate':$("#txtEndDate").val()
    },
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (res) {
    alert(res.children[0].innerHTML);
  }
});
```

Code in CommonServices.asmx

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public string SubmitRequestInterface2(string fromDate, string toDate)
    {
        try
        {
            //string fromDate = 
Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["fromDate"]);
            //string toDate = 
Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["toDate"]);
            ClsProcess objProcess = new ClsProcess();
            objProcess.Process(fromDate, toDate);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }

        return "Hello World";
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to debug your code to figure out why. Consider adding logging or checking your windows event log to see if the exception is logged there.

Comment: How do I debug my code as the service request does not post to the server.

Comment: If you are getting a 500 it is hitting the server but the server fails to process the request for whatever reason. Again, check your logs.